# Validating Javascript Model

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm looking to create a model in JavaScript. Here is an example of the code that I have so far:

```
// Person model
function Person(firstName, age) {
    // Check first name
    if (firstName) {
        if (typeof firstName === 'string') {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        } 
        else throw new Error('The first name is not a string.');
    } 
    else throw new Error('First name is a required field.');

    // Check age
    if (age) {
        if (typeof age === 'number') {
            if (age < 0) {
                throw new Error('The age provided is a negative.');
            } 
            else {
                this.age = age;
            }
        } 
        else throw new Error('The age provided is not a number.');
    } 
    else throw new Error('Age is a required field.');
}

// Example usage
try {
    var joel = new Person('Joel', 30);
    console.log(joel);
}    

catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

Is this an idiomatic approach to the solution? And if so is there a way in which I can improve it?

Comment: Seems inflexible, sometimes one needs temporarily invalid objects

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to create `isValid()` method instead of exceptions and `getValidationErrors()` to get array of all errors instead of one error message with exception.

```js
var joel = new Person('Joel', 30);
if( ! joel.isValid() ) {
    console.log(joel.getValidationErrors());
}
```

Also you can create some validation function like

```
validate({
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    age: {
        type: 'number',
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 150
    }
}, {
    name: firstName,
    age:  age
});
```

Which will return array of errors. If array length is 0 then validation passed.